# Django 3.2 Project with DB2 (IBM_DB driver)

Tags: python, django, db2, db2-luw

Currently, I am working in developing a web application with Python 3.8.10, Django 3.2 and IBM_DB_DJANGO 1.5.0.0.

When I am trying the first step to move from sqlite3 to DB2, I type the command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Unfortunately, I got the error as below

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0401N  The data types of the operands for the operation "IN" are not compatible or comparable.  SQLSTATE=42818\r SQLCODE=-401
```

There are tables being created and including: AUTH_GROUP, AUTH_GROUP_PERMISSIONS, AUTH_PERMISSION, DJANGO_MIGRATIONS.

There is one records added in the Django_migration only.  I would like to know how I could confirm whether it is good to use.

db2level output ``` DB21085I This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10058" with level identifier "0609010E". Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.0.8", "s160901", "IP23998", and Fix Pack "8". Product is installed at "/opt/IBM/db2/V10.5".

Pip freeze result  `asgiref==3.4.1  colorama==0.4.4  Django==3.2  ibm-db==3.1.0  ibm-db-django==1.5.0.0  pytz==2021.3  regex==2021.10.8  six==1.16.0  sqlparse==0.4.2`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cannot recreate your symptom wtih python 3.8.10, ibm_db 3.1.0, ibm_db_django 1.5.0.0,  Django 3.2.    Please edit your question to show the plain text output of the `db2level` command on the (aix) Db2-Server, along with the plain text output of `pip freeze` on your python environment. Please don't use comments to add facts.

Comment: db2level
$ db2level output
```
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable:
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10058" with level
identifier "0609010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.0.8", "s160901", "IP23998", and Fix Pack
"8".
Product is installed at "/opt/IBM/db2/V10.5".
```
Pip freeze result
```
asgiref==3.4.1
colorama==0.4.4
Django==3.2
ibm-db==3.1.0
ibm-db-django==1.5.0.0
pytz==2021.3
regex==2021.10.8
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

Comment: "Please don't use comments to add facts". Did you read that? Please edit your question and add the information.

Answer (score 0):

The symptom you reported (SQL0401N  when migrate is running 0001_initial.py)  in the question is caused by use of BOOLEAN datatype in some migrations.

With the Db2-LUW version 10.5, the BOOLEAN was not fully implemented for applications, it was only available in compound-SQL but not yet in applications.

Please note that Db2-LUW version 10.5 ended support by IBM on 30/April/2020. You should already have upgraded unless you bought extended support.

You can avoid this problem by using a more recent version of Db2-LUW, for example v11.1 or v11.5, both of which properly support BOOLEAN in applications.

Other workarounds may be possible (e.g adjusting the migrations, or altering how BooleanField is modeled etc. ) , so you can open a ticket with the developers og ibm_db_django on github and ask.